# C++ optional initialization issue with Clang?

Tags: c++, clang, c++20, option-type

Following code compiles fine in C++20 with MSVC and GCC, but fails with clang.

```
#include <optional>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct A {
  string s;
};

int main() {
  [[maybe_unused]] optional<A> a{in_place, "hello"};
}
```

Check [this link](https://godbolt.org/z/5YGxje5vs).

It fails with C++17 in all 3 compilers.
Is this a clang C++20 bug?